# EF6 How to insert primary key of a newly added row into a different column of a new row of the same table before save savechanges is called?

Tags: entity-framework-6

```
Seq      RefSeq    Name
1        null      Manager  
2        1         Employee
```

I'm trying to insert multiple rows in a table. When I insert the second row shown above I need to be able to insert the Seq of the first row in the RefSeq column of the second row. I need to be able to do this before SaveChanges() is called. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can try override the function SaveChanges on your Context Class and add this code:

```
public override int SaveChanges ( ) {
            var lastSeq = this.[yourTable].OrderByDescending ( c => c.Seq ).FirstOrDefault ( ).RefSeq;

            foreach(var  ent in this.ChangeTracker.Entries ( ).Where ( x => x.Entity is [theClassofYourEntity] ) ) {
                ( ( [ theClassofYourEntity ] ) ent.Entity ).RefSeq = lastSeq;
            }    

            return base.SaveChanges ( );
        }
```

replace [*****] with your values or names of tables and entity class´s

(this only work when save one by one)